# jquery - get array from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the output of the variable as below -

```
console.log(arrayForPrice);

93: {id: "93", code: "color", label: "Color", options: Array(3), position: "1"}
141: {id: "141", code: "size", label: "Size", options: Array(3), position: "0"}
```

on Json stringify -

```
{
"93":{"id":"93","code":"color","label":"Color","options":[{"id":"50","label":"Blue","products":["1216","1219","1222"]},{"id":"58","label":"Red","products":["1217","1220","1223"]},{"id":"60","label":"Yellow","products":["1218","1221","1224"]}],"position":"1"},
"141":{"id":"141","code":"size","label":"Size","options":[{"id":"168","label":"S","products":["1216","1217","1218"]},{"id":"169","label":"M","products":["1219","1220","1221"]},{"id":"170","label":"L","products":["1222","1223","1224"]}],"position":"0"}
}
```

I have a requirement to match the out put of another variable with the key of the two objects as shared above. But the issue I am facing is I am not able to crack and go inside the key. I want the array which is in the key `options`

The code which I am trying is as follows -

```
$.each(arrayForPrice,function(i) {

    $.each(data.programs[i], function (key, val) {
        console.log(key);
    });
});
```

But it is not working. How do I get to the options array?

Comment: Please show the **actual** `console.log` output of `arrayForPrice`, or better yet, the exact output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayForPrice))`. It's not clear what it is (it looks like it may be an object that isn't an array, but it's impossible to be sure). That said, even if it's a non-object array, from what you've quoted `i` would be `"93"` and then `"141"` in the `each` call.

Comment: I have updated my answer with jsonstringify console.log

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. You want to find the value of a key and if it exists in any object?

Comment: I basically want to fetch the values of options array inside the 141 key. But before that I want to apply a check if the key is 141 then it should happen. Basically it can be 141 or whatever, I will be applying an if condition later on but my curreny problem is to get options array.

Comment: So as I said, `i` in your `$.each` callback will be the IDs. It sounds like you're having trouble accessing the data from `data.programs`, which you haven't shown. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you can access the elements like this

```
 for(var key in arrayForPrice){
  var obj = arrayForPrice[key];
  var optionArray = obj.options;
  optionArray.forEach(function(data){
   // Access the elements are 
  }); 
 }
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined

Comment: updated the code.

Comment: Their is issue in closing bracket of the for loop, can you please and update so that I can approve.

Comment: updated , you can run the code now!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrayForPrice = {
"93":{"id":"93","code":"color","label":"Color","options":[{"id":"50","label":"Blue","products":["1216","1219","1222"]},{"id":"58","label":"Red","products":["1217","1220","1223"]},{"id":"60","label":"Yellow","products":["1218","1221","1224"]}],"position":"1"},
"141":{"id":"141","code":"size","label":"Size","options":[{"id":"168","label":"S","products":["1216","1217","1218"]},{"id":"169","label":"M","products":["1219","1220","1221"]},{"id":"170","label":"L","products":["1222","1223","1224"]}],"position":"0"}
};


for(var i in arrayForPrice){
 console.log(arrayForPrice[i].options);
}
```

Comment: The `$.each` the OP is already using does this already.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayForPrice.length; i++){
    var priceItem = arrayForPrice[i];
    for(var key in priceItem){
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Above is a way to access all keys..

To access the options array I would go for something like :

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayForPrice.length; i++){
     var priceItem = arrayForPrice[i];
     if(typeof priceItem['options'] != 'undefined'){
         var optionsArray = priceItem['options'];
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you get help

```js
var data = {
"93":{"id":"93","code":"color","label":"Color","options":[{"id":"50","label":"Blue","products":["1216","1219","1222"]},{"id":"58","label":"Red","products":["1217","1220","1223"]},{"id":"60","label":"Yellow","products":["1218","1221","1224"]}],"position":"1"},
"141":{"id":"141","code":"size","label":"Size","options":[{"id":"168","label":"S","products":["1216","1217","1218"]},{"id":"169","label":"M","products":["1219","1220","1221"]},{"id":"170","label":"L","products":["1222","1223","1224"]}],"position":"0"}
}



$.each(data,function(index,val) {
    console.log(val.options); //Here you can go inside options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `$.each` the OP is already using does this already.